# MRI (brain tumor) image processing and segmentation, skull removing

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, image-segmentation

I need help for image segmentation. I have a MRI image of brain with tumor. I need to remove cranium (skull) from MRI and then segment only tumor object. How could I do that in python? with image processing. I have tried make contours, but I don't know how to find and remove the largest contour and get only brain without a skull. 
Thank's a lot.

```
def get_brain(img):
  row_size = img.shape[0]
  col_size = img.shape[1]

  mean = np.mean(img)
  std = np.std(img)
  img = img - mean
  img = img / std

 middle = img[int(col_size / 5):int(col_size / 5 * 4), int(row_size / 5):int(row_size / 5 * 4)]
  mean = np.mean(middle)
  max = np.max(img)
  min = np.min(img)


  img[img == max] = mean
  img[img == min] = mean

  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(np.reshape(middle, [np.prod(middle.shape), 1]))
  centers = sorted(kmeans.cluster_centers_.flatten())
  threshold = np.mean(centers)
  thresh_img = np.where(img < threshold, 1.0, 0.0)  # threshold the image


  eroded = morphology.erosion(thresh_img, np.ones([3, 3]))
  dilation = morphology.dilation(eroded, np.ones([5, 5]))
```

These images are similar to the ones I'm looking at:

[image: Skull + Brain]

[image: Skull + Brain 2]

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You might be interested in [Nipype](http://nipype.readthedocs.io/en/0.12.0/index.html), particularly the [skullfinder](http://nipype.readthedocs.io/en/0.12.0/interfaces/generated/nipype.interfaces.brainsuite.brainsuite.html#skullfinder) functions.

Comment: you can use regionprops to find the properties of regions like perimeter, area, major axis, etc and use these to remove false regions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Preliminaries

Some preliminary code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import extrema
from skimage.morphology import watershed as skwater

def ShowImage(title,img,ctype):
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
  if ctype=='bgr':
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)       # get b,g,r
    rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb
    plt.imshow(rgb_img)
  elif ctype=='hsv':
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
    plt.imshow(rgb)
  elif ctype=='gray':
    plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
  elif ctype=='rgb':
    plt.imshow(img)
  else:
    raise Exception("Unknown colour type")
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.title(title)
  plt.show()
```

For reference, here's one of the brain+skulls you linked to:

```
#Read in image
img           = cv2.imread('brain.png')
gray          = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ShowImage('Brain with Skull',gray,'gray')
```

[image: Brain with Skull]

## Extracting a Mask

If the pixels in the image can be classified into two different intensity classes, that is, if they have a bimodal histogram, then [Otsu's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) can be used to threshold them into a binary mask. Let's check that assumption.

```
#Make a histogram of the intensities in the grayscale image
plt.hist(gray.ravel(),256)
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram]

Okay, the data is nicely bimodal. Let's apply the threshold and see how we do.

```
#Threshold the image to binary using Otsu's method
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ShowImage('Applying Otsu',thresh,'gray')
```

[image: Tresholded brain+skull]

Things are easier to see if we overlay our mask onto the original image

```
colormask = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
colormask[thresh!=0] = np.array((0,0,255))
blended = cv2.addWeighted(img,0.7,colormask,0.1,0)
ShowImage('Blended', blended, 'bgr')
```

[image: Mask overlaid on brain+skull]

## Extracting the Brain

The overlap of the brain (shown in red) with the mask is so perfect, that we'll stop right here. To do so, let's extract the connected components and find the largest one, which will be the brain.

```
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh)

#Get the area taken by each component. Ignore label 0 since this is the background.
marker_area = [np.sum(markers==m) for m in range(np.max(markers)) if m!=0] 
#Get label of largest component by area
largest_component = np.argmax(marker_area)+1 #Add 1 since we dropped zero above                        
#Get pixels which correspond to the brain
brain_mask = markers==largest_component

brain_out = img.copy()
#In a copy of the original image, clear those pixels that don't correspond to the brain
brain_out[brain_mask==False] = (0,0,0)
ShowImage('Connected Components',brain_out,'rgb')
```

[image: Brain extracted with connected components]

## Considering the Second Brain

Running this again with your second image produces a mask with many holes:

[image: Second Brain]

We can close many of these holes using a [closing transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)):

```
brain_mask = np.uint8(brain_mask)
kernel = np.ones((8,8),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(brain_mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
ShowImage('Closing', closing, 'gray')
```

[image: Brain mask with holes closed]

We can now extract the brain:

```
brain_out = img.copy()
#In a copy of the original image, clear those pixels that don't correspond to the brain
brain_out[closing==False] = (0,0,0)
ShowImage('Connected Components',brain_out,'rgb')
```

[image: Second brain with better mask]

If you need to cite this for some reason:

> Richard Barnes. (2018). Using Otsu's method for skull-brain segmentation (v1.0.1). Zenodo. https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.6042312

Comment: It was informative, an alternative to the one I was wandering, thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps tried to use python skull_stripping.py
You can modify the parameters but it normally works good.

There are some new studies using deep learning for skull stripping which I found it interesting:

https://github.com/mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation/tree/master/skull-stripping

Comment: you should post some explanation also. rather then only link

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jul 28 17:10:56 2021

@author: K Somasundaram, ka.somasundaram@gmail.com
"""
import numpy as npy
from skimage.filters  import threshold_otsu
from skimage import measure
# import image reading module image from matplotlib
import matplotlib.image as img
#import image ploting module pyplot from matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
inim=img.imread('015.bmp')
#Find the dimension of the input image
dimn=inim.shape
print('dim=',dimn)
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(inim)
#-----------------------------------------------
# Find a threshold for the image using Otsu method in filters
th=threshold_otsu(inim)
print('Threshold  = ',th)
# Binarize using threshold th
binim1=inim>th
plt.figure(2)
plt.imshow(binim1)
#--------------------------------------------------
# Erode the binary image with a structuring element
from skimage.morphology import disk
import skimage.morphology as morph
#Erode it with a radius of 5
eroded_image=morph.erosion(binim1,disk(3))
plt.figure(3)
plt.imshow(eroded_image)
#---------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------

# label the binar image
labelimg=measure.label(eroded_image,background=0)
plt.figure(4)
plt.imshow(labelimg)

#--------------------------------------------------
# Find area of the connected regiond
prop=measure.regionprops(labelimg)
# Find the number of objecte in the image 
ncount=len(prop)
print ( 'Number of regions=',ncount)
#-----------------------------------------------------
# Find the LLC index
argmax=0
maxarea=0
#Find the largets connected region
for i in range(ncount):
    if(prop[i].area >maxarea):
      maxarea=prop[i].area
      argmax=i
print('max area=',maxarea,'arg max=',argmax)

print('values=',[region.area for region in prop])
# Take only the largest connected region
 # Generate a mask of size of th einput image with all zeros
bmask=npy.zeros(inim.shape,dtype=npy.uint8)
# Set all pixel values in whole image to the LCC index to 1
bmask[labelimg == (argmax+1)] =1


plt.figure(5)
plt.imshow(bmask)

#------------------------------------------------
#Dilate the isolated region to recover the pixels lost in erosion
dilated_mask=morph.dilation(bmask,disk(6))
plt.figure(6)
plt.imshow(dilated_mask)
#---------------------------------------
# Extract the brain using the barinmask
brain=inim*dilated_mask
plt.figure(7)
plt.imshow(brain)

-----------------------------------------
Input Image
--------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).